# Are there efficient algorithms to factorise in $\mathbb{N}[X]$?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, factorization

One way to do factorisation in $\mathbb{N}[X]$ is to use an algorithm to factorise in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and then to combine some factor to find a factorisation in $\mathbb{N}[X]$. Note that the factorisation in $\mathbb{N}[X]$ is not unique, e.g.,

$$x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1) = (x^4+x^2+1)(x+1) = (x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Comment: If you're still here, Sylvain, you should edit your question so it's actually a question.